# CSV file - count distinct, group by, sum

Tags: powershell

I have a file that looks like the following;

```
- Visitor ID,Revenue,Channel,Flight
- 1234,100,Email,BA123
- 2345,200,PPC,BA112
- 456,150,Email,BA456
```

I need to produce a file that contains;

```
The count of distinct Visitor IDs (3)
The total revenue (450)
The count of each Channel
Email 2
PPC 2
The count of each Flight
BA123 1
BA112 1
BA456 1
```

So far I have the following code, however when executing this on the `350MB` file, it takes too long and in some cases breaks the `memory limit`. As I have to run this `function` on `multiple columns`, it is going through the file many times. I ideally need to do this in one file pass.

```
$file = 'log.txt'

function GroupBy($columnName)
{
    $objects = Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" $file | Group-Object $columnName |
       Select-Object @{n=$columnName;e={$_.Group[0].$columnName}}, Count

      for($i=0;$i -lt $objects.count;$I++) {
     $line += $columnName +"|"+$objects[$I]."$columnName" +"|Count|"+ $objects[$I].'Count' + $OFS

    }
    return $line
}

$finalOutput += GroupBy "Channel"
$finalOutput += GroupBy "Flight"


Write-Host $finalOutput
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Have you looked at ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050408/import-csv-groupby-sum?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your are importing the CSV again for each column is what is killing your script.  Try to do the loading once, then re-use the data.  For example:

```
$data = Import-Csv .\data.csv

$flights = $data | Group-Object Flight -NoElement | ForEach-Object {[PsCustomObject]@{Flight=$_.Name;Count=$_.Count}}
$visitors = ($data | Group-Object "Visitor ID" | Measure-Object).Count
$revenue = ($data | Measure-Object Revenue -Sum).Sum
$channel = $data | Group-Object Channel -NoElement | ForEach-Object {[PsCustomObject]@{Channel=$_.Name;Count=$_.Count}}
```

You can display the data like this:

```
"Revenue : $revenue"
"Visitors: $visitors"
$flights | Format-Table -AutoSize
$channel | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I did try your code out on a 350MB file. There is now 12 GB of memory being used and what I can only imagine to be a lot of paging going on. Has Powershell always been this awful ?!

Comment: PowerShell is based on .NET Framework, which has it's own garbage collection that runs in the background.  Objects are not always immediately disposed of (thus freeing memory).  You can force .NET to garbage collect now by using `[GC]::Collect()`, though it [isn't usually recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect).

Comment: When I hit greater amounts of data I find that Group-By can be slow and memory consuming. In those cases I usually just use hash maps to get exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At C:\Users\fitches\Documents\Clients\TUI\GMP Data Summary\gmp.ps1:19 char:1
+ $visitors = ($data | Group-Object "CMid Visitor" | Measure-Object).Co ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work - using hashmaps.

- Pros: It will be faster/use less memory.
- Cons: It is less readable
  by far than `Group-Object`, and requires more code.
- Make it even less memory-hungry: Read the CSV-file line by line

  ```
  $data = Import-CSV -Path "C:\temp\data.csv" -Delimiter ","
  $DistinctVisitors = @{}
  $TotalRevenue = 0
  $ChannelCount = @{}
  $FlightCount = @{}

  $data | ForEach-Object {
      $DistinctVisitors[$_.'Visitor ID'] = $true
      $TotalRevenue += $_.Revenue

      if (-not $ChannelCount.ContainsKey($_.Channel)) {
          $ChannelCount[$_.Channel] = 0
      }
      $ChannelCount[$_.Channel] += 1

      if (-not $FlightCount.ContainsKey($_.Flight)) {
          $FlightCount[$_.Flight] = 0
      }
      $FlightCount[$_.Flight] += 1
  }

  $DistinctVisitorsCount = $DistinctVisitors.Keys | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

  Write-Output "The count of distinc Visitor IDs $DistinctVisitorsCount"
  Write-Output "The total revenue $TotalRevenue"
  Write-Output "The Count of each Channel"
  $ChannelCount.Keys | ForEach-Object {
      Write-Output "$_ $($ChannelCount[$_])"
  }
  Write-Output "The count of each Flight"
  $FlightCount.Keys | ForEach-Object {
      Write-Output "$_ $($FlightCount[$_])"
  }
  ```